# Reputation earned shows a loss after earning 200 reputation and losing some afterwards

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, linked-accounts

Recently, I've earned 200 reputation on Stack Overflow. After that, I received 100 additional reputation on my associated accounts on other sites.  This, of course, makes me happy! Incidentally, my reputation fell below 200 because someone unaccepted one of my answers and I don't disagree.

But I noticed something strange, my reputation earned for the week and month shows **-110** and **-40** respectively.

I think it should have been a **-15** point difference of reputation, not **-110**.  This can't be right.   I shouldn't have lost that much reputation just because someone unaccepted my answer.

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening?

### Update:

The only place where my reputation is shown as wrong is on the Stack Overflow users page.

To see it, go to [SO Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) and enter `mockertim` in the search box:

[image]

You should see what I mean.

Please, **do not upvote or downvote my posts on Stack Overflow right now just to experiment**.

Comment: Having an answer un-accepted loses you 15 points. Something else must have happened to lose you 110 points - were any of your contributions flagged and deleted recently?

Comment: No. I even don't have any red lines on my reputation graph.

Comment: You didn't lose 110 on your SO account - maybe 110 places in the ranking by losing 15 points?

Comment: I don't see a 110 point rep loss. Where do you see the -110?

Comment: I see it in the week and month rating of all users on StackOverflow.

Comment: This "loss" will reverse itself once you rise above 200 points on SO again. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Mocker - I upvoted one of your good answers, you're back above 200 now anyway. Don't get too upset about rep loss - cream rises in the end.

Comment: @Jeff my bet is an unrelated, deleted contribution. But only a mod can tell for sure.

Comment: You may have to clear the associations and then reassociate the accounts to get the points back.

Comment: And don't think twice about reputation here on meta; the votes here mean different things.

Comment: @Pekka: After seeing ChrisF's comment on the (now) deleted answer, his explanation makes a lot of sense in this case.  It is unfortunately being displayed incorrectly due to the "loss" of bonus points.

Comment: @Jeff ah, okay, interesting!

Comment: I've rephrased your question so it's more neutral.  This is a valid bug I think but you made it sound like someone stole something from you.  I hope I didn't loose you on this.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado I agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "problem" was caused by the loss of the association bonus when the account dipped below 200 rep. As bonus happened at some point in the past the headline figure shows a change of -100 compared to *last week*.

Once the reputation on one account (in this case SO) rises back above 200 the bonus will be restored.

It appears that the bonus isn't restored automatically but is assigned to the account as it can be seen in the https://stackoverflow.com/reputation report at the top as the line:

```
-- bonuses (100)
```

The final reputation figure also includes this value (i.e. it's over 300).

Clicking the "recalculate rep" button at the bottom of the `/reputation` page should sort everything out.

Reputation displayed in other places - e.g. flair or on your [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/df932341-cebf-4441-8135-06cbd23b2d04?tab=reputation) will take a little while to catch up as it's cached.

Comment: There is still some "problem". I've updated my question once again.

Comment: @Mocker - and I've updated my answer. Also you are worrying too much. These things usually sort themselves out, usually after 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, again. Yep. I behave crazy a little. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

People are free to accept different answers.

How about going back to that question and adding more value - looking at what the other question did to beat yours (if the asker accepted another answer).

---

**Update**

As per the updated question, the users page does show his weekly reputation as -70. Surely this must be a bug?

Comment: I don't accert that the man who accepted another answer is wrong. Have you read my question up to the end?

Comment: Yes. Please show my where there's any "injustice" in this case?

Comment: The loss of **110** point of reputation instead of **15** in all users week rating on SO.

Comment: You didn't lose 110 on SO...

Comment: See my updated question. You are right ... but only partially.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not lose 110 points of *reputation* at all (as you noted by looking at your reputation graph). It looks like you dropped 110 *places* in the reputation table.

The "score tables" you refer to are ordered by score, but the "place" you come is a different number to your actual score.

It is easily possible that by dropping only 15 actual reputation points, you could have dropped behind 110 people on the scoreboard... thus losing 110 places.

This is most likely what happened.

If you instead had increased by 15 points, you might well jump ahead of 110 people and thus your "score" on the scoreboard would increase by 110 for just those 15 points of reputation.

[Edit: looks like I was wrong here... I'd delete this answer, but looks like the comments are actually important... :)]

Comment: No, he "lost" 100 points because he temporarily lost the reputation bonus that comes with associating accounts where one has > 200 rep. Once that's been restored he won't have lost any rep.

Comment: Throw that in as an answer @ChrisF, that seems to be THE most likely cause.

Comment: @ChrisF Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. My reputation is now grater than 200, but on SO Users page it's still in big minus.

Comment: @MockerTim - in that case I'm at a loss. Did you try clearing the associations and re-associating the accounts?

Comment: @ChrisF Yep. I tried it now. Nothing happened.

Comment: @MockerTim - does the page at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation have a line `-- bonuses   (100)` at the top (2nd line I think) and what does the final rep score say at the bottom?

Comment: @ChrisF total votes: 74
-- bonuses   (100)...-- 2011-06-14 rep +40   = 339

Comment: @MockerTim - right - just hit the "recalculate rep" button and you get the 100 points back.

Comment: @ChrisF Where can I find this magic button?

Comment: @Mocker - It's at the bottom of the `/reputation` page. I've added an answer that summarises all this